# sw320dp layout blocks xlarge layout

Tags: android, layout

I made an extra layout for the S3 (rebel of all layouts) and people said, using a layout-sw320dp is good for the s3. Everything worked, the s3 chose this folder and the layout looks great on the s3.

But when I try to run my app on a 10" tablet, the tablet uses the same folder like the s3 which is totally wrong.

How can I make the sw320dp layout visible only to the s3 or at least how can I make 10" tablets use the xhdpi folders? I already read, that the android system thinks, because sw360 is a "new" type, it's the best. But I don't know how I can avoid that..

Thanks

Comment: try putting your layout for `s3` in `sw320dp-normal` directory

Comment: That brings up the same error. I can't imagine that there are so less people who have a problem with it

Answer (score 2):

This is because of higher order of precedence of `sw<???>dp` qualifier in Android. `res-sw<???>dp` has got the 2nd highest precedence in the order of qualifiers.

See [Configuration qualifier Table](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#table2). This is the default order in which Android takes the directories in resource folders. So basically whatever folder you provide which have lower precedence, Android wolud not take that. See [How Android Finds the Best-matching Resource](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources).

Here `sw320dp` means devices with at least 320dp of shortest width. Both S3 and 10" tablets come under that. So Android always take that folder for devices which have shortest width of 320dp.

These are some alternatives you can do:

- Make layouts like `drawable-720dp`(10") and `drawable-600dp`(7") for
  tablets. The problem with giving `sw<???>dp` is that it's been introduced only in API 13 only. So tablets with API < 13. can't use that.
- Change the layout for high density phones to layouts with lower
  precedence values.

  - I basically support this method. This way you can give more support
    to lower API devices.

Comment: What about the standard "layout" directory, when is this picked up?