# Android is not picking right dimens.xml file from values folder

Tags: android, android-layout, android-screen-support, android-screen

I have created different dimens.xml files and placed them in appropriate values folder.

I have the following "value" folders defined

***values, 
values-large,
values-normal,
values-small,
values-sw320dp,
values-sw320dp-land,
values-sw480dp,
values-sw600dp,
values-sw720dp and
values-sw720dp-land***

The problem is when I install the app on phone <= 5 inches, dimens.xml from ***values-sw320dp*** is selected by Android. The selection is independent of screen density.

I have tested the app on S4, Moto G, S4 Mini and some 2.3 device. The results are the same throughout.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16454751/sw320dp-layout-blocks-xlarge-layout

Comment: I am able to solve my problem by appending hdpi, xhdpi and xxhdpi to values-sw320dp. 

I created the following folders values-sw320dp-hdpi, values-sw320dp-xhdpi and values-sw320dp-xxhdpi and added the corresponding dimens.xml file. Now the correct dimensions are picked.

Comment: Great :) Yes, [qualifiers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources) are required as mentioned in that SO post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what is the problem in the way you are trying. But I always create values folders like this **values, values-ldpi, values-mdpi, values-hdpi, values-xhdpi, values-w360dp-mdpi, values-w600dp-mdpi and so on**. Its always work for me.

Comment: The purpose of dp gets defeated by defining values folder with density qualifier

Answer (score 10):

Well it is now clear to me that `values-sw320dp` will be the only folder from which `dimens.xml` will be picked as phones <= 5 inches fall into that category.

The mistake I was making was ignoring the screen density for 320dp size screens.

So the solution I found works is to create different value folders based on screen density i.e. create folders named `values-sw320dp-ldpi, values-sw320dp-mdpi, values-sw320dp-hdpi, values-sw320dp-xhdpi and values-sw320dp-xxhdpi` and put the corresponding `dimens.xml` files in them.

I hope this helps to people who might stumble upon this problem.

Comment: This makes no sense. Screen sizes and screen resolutions are not the same. You can have a screen size smaller than 5 inches but a resolution that exceeds 320 dp.

Comment: @AndroidDev Please read my question again, I had asked "The problem is when I install the app on phone <= 5 inches, dimens.xml from values-sw320dp is selected by Android. The selection is independent of screen density." 

I know for a fact that screen size and resolutions are not the same, yet in my case values-sw480dp configurations were ignored, the reason being that none of my phone had above xhdpi resolution, please see this (ldpi (low) ~120dpi
mdpi (medium) ~160dpi
hdpi (high) ~240dpi
xhdpi (extra-high) ~320dpi) from http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: But I guess that if you use any QHD phone of today you would have to use 480dp or 640dp configurations, you can future proof your app by doing this.